# Is there a Linux software to spell check .po files?

Tags: linux, software-rec, spell-check, translation, i18n

I am translating some po-files and I would like to run a spell checker over them. I have Ubuntu 10.10 and use gtranslator. As far as I know, gtranslator can't spellcheck the whole file.

I tried ispell: `$ ispell lordsawar-0.2.0-pre4.de.po` - this doesn't work, as English and German strings, as well as some programming-relevant comments appear in the .po-file.

Do you know any program running on Ubuntu which can spell check po-files?

Comment: It's been 11 years and Gtranslator still can't spell-check a file without you manually clicking on every translation entry.

Answer (score 3):

I've just pushed a po file spell checker to github: https://github.com/holygeek/pospelchek

The behavior imitates aspell wherein it shows you the mispelled word and suggests corrections.

Run it like this:

```
$ pospelchek -l de_DE lordsawar-0.2.0-pre4.de.po
```

or to get the man page:

```
$ pospelchek -h
```

Comment: You'll have to install the relevant dictionaries for the languages that you want to spellcheck. These are the same dictionaries that aspell uses.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this online tool: [poeditor.com](http://poeditor.com/), it doesn't have an actual spell check option, but you can have a translator do that for you via the platform as a contributor to your project, or you could try to compare your translation to an automatic one that the program can generate.

Answer (score 0):

There is [spellcheck](https://github.com/Changaco/misc-scripts/#spellcheck), an `aspell` wrapper script written in python that adds basic support for `.po` files (requires [Babel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Babel)).

Answer (score 0):

`emacs` can spell-check PO files in [PO-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PoMode#h5o-2).